# Ansible: Trying to parse out Loopback0 IP Address

Tags: ansible, cisco

I am trying to store the IP address of my `loopback0` as variable. I can call the `ipv4` information, but it doesn't let me call the address information. [Scrubbed Info for Privacy]

Code:

```
- name: Configure IPSLA on Americas Router
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: IP_SLA
  connection: local
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Gather Switch Info
      ios_facts:

    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: ansible_facts["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"]
...
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Configure IPSLA on Americas Router] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gather Switch Info] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_net_interfaces": {"Loopback0": {"bandwidth": 8000000, "description": null, "duplex": null, "ipv4": [{"address": "10.x.x.x", "subnet": "32"}], "lineprotocol": "up ", "macaddress": null, "mediatype": null, "mtu": 1514, "operstatus": "up", "type": null}

TASK [Debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "ansible_facts[\"net_interfaces\"][\"Loopback0\"][\"ipv4\"]": [
        {
            "address": "10.x.x.x",
            "subnet": "32"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try and call the address:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
  var: ansible_facts["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"]["address"]
```

I end up with this error:

```
TASK [Debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "ansible_facts[\"net_interfaces\"][\"Loopback0\"][\"ipv4\"][\"address\"]": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'list object' has no attribute 'address'"
```

How do I get the address stored as a variable so I can use it in future tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets in:

```
ok: [host] => {
    "ansible_facts[\"net_interfaces\"][\"Loopback0\"][\"ipv4\"]": [
        {
            "address": "10.x.x.x",
            "subnet": "32"
        }
    ]
}
```

Indicate this `["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"]` is an array with a single element.

Use `[0]` to indicate the first element of the array, as demonstrated by the following code:

```
ansible_facts["net_interfaces"]["Loopback0"]["ipv4"][0]["address"]
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I will do some more learning about arrays vs. lists, etc. Thanks!